# When I use fo-dicom to update a DICOM tag the C# form changes size

Tags: c#, winforms, fo-dicom

I have a problem with fo-dicom in C# form.
When I use fo-dicom to update a DICOM tag the form changes size and everything gets smaller.
The problem appear when I use **dataset.Add**
I created an example with only a simple form with a button, this is all the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test_DICOM_view_problem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Dicom.DicomDataset dataset = new Dicom.DicomDataset();

            dataset.Add(Dicom.DicomTag.Rows, "1024");

        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMEr2_HHBvxtBJElforv9D5BBpqvuu8N/view?usp=sharing) is the form before clicking the button, and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vgxhZjQin1BzBz5WHWutOGJKH_eN2if5/view?usp=sharing) after.

The problem appear only when I execute my form from Visual Studio GUI in Debug/Release mode, but it does not appear if I run the exe directly.

I uploaded my code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sTWeoTaPH0QczFl90EgIhMx6uB8jsxqX/view?usp=sharing).

My configuration is:

- Windows 10
- .Net Framework 4.7.1
- Visual Studio 2017 last version (15.6.5)
- fo-dicom 3.0.2

Thanks for your help,
 
Davide

Comment: Sorry. Downloaded your code. Also executed on windows 10 1709 in visual studio 2017 15.6.5 under framework 4.7.1.
When I press the button in the form, then the size of the window does not change at all. Is this only when you do something with fo-dicom? if you for example create a new instance of System.Data.Dataset (SQL) in the button-click-handler or any other instance, is it then the same? Or only if you load fo-dicom?

Comment: What I see now: It's not that the window size changed, but the whole window scaled! also the button and the font in the button is smaller after the handler. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032946/why-does-visual-studio-2015-form-size-changes-when-debugging-c-cli. Do you have some monitor-scaling-settings on your system?

Comment: Yes, my monitor has the **recommended** settings of 125%. I tried to set my monitor to 100% and the problem **disappered**. Do you now a way to avoid this behaviour keepening the raccomended setting of 125%? I have this problem only when I use fo-dicom. I've seen that when it's launched **dataset.Add**, it's loaded some DLL like PresentationCore. So, the problem could be related to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242963/windows-forms-window-changes-its-size-when-i-create-a-wpf-window)?

Comment: I have searched the code and the method "SetProcessDPIAware" as pointed in your link is never called. But since this seems only to happen when you start from within visual studio, I would say this is a bug there. Your final .exe works finde, doesn't it?

Comment: A workaround would be, to load fo-dicom directly on startup. For example in the OnLoad method of the form you could just create a dummy DicomDataset. then the resizing happens immediatelly after starting the application and not somewhen the user performs some action.

Comment: Yes my exe works fine, it's just running inside Visual Studio that has this effect. 
Your proposal could be a workaround, but the form has strange effects. You can see one of the most stupid effects in this image ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ys3AiisiS4y4tMi-xET38O2hh_slmYT/view?usp=sharing)) at the border. I tried also in my real application and cause even worse effects, with overlapping buttons and more.